# Sync values between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problem with my oracle SQL query. So what I am trying to do is like syncing values between two tables. When there is an identical head_mark occurs between two tables, then the SURFACE value should be synced and update according to the surface in the other table. So my query is like this,

```
update painting_qc_hist pqh set pqh.current_qc_surface = mda.surface
where exists
(select 1 from master_drawing_assigned mda where md.head_mark = mda.head_mark)
```

and my table structure is,

in the MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED,

```
HEAD_MARK ID SURFACE
SMSBM180  1  59.96
SMSBM181  1  60.3
```

and in the PAINTING_QC_HIST, the CURRENT_QC_SURFACE should be updated according to the same headmark with SURFACE values in MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED

```
HEAD_MARK ID CURRENT_QC_SURFACE
SMSBM180  1  
SMSBM181  1
```

so the desired result should be,

```
HEAD_MARK ID CURRENT_QC_SURFACE
SMSBM180  1  59.96
SMSBM181  1  60.3
```

Please help me, whats wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically more efficient when implementing as a [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

```
MERGE INTO painting_qc_hist dst
USING (SELECT surface, head_mark FROM master_drawing_assigned) src
ON (dst.head_mark = src.head_mark)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dst.current_qc_surface = src.surface;
```

Comment: amazing albin, its effective and easy to understand .. KUDOS

Comment: Yep, the merge is really handy especially when you also want to insert new rows when there are no existing matches for your id column.

Comment: what if on the same identical headmark, the two surface values are different, will they get synced based on the surface value on the master_drawing_assigned ?

Comment: Yes `painting_qc_hist.current_qc_surface` will always be overwritten with the value from `master_drawing_assigned.surface`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
UPDATE TABLE PAINTING_QC_HIST A
SET A.CURRENT_QC_SURFACE = (SELECT SURFACE 
                            FROM MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED B
                            WHERE A.HEAD_MARK = B.HEAD_MARK)
WHERE A.HEAD_MARK = (SELECT A.ID FROM PAINTING_QC_HIST A);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Are you sure with your code ? because I tried it and it doesn't work